# url not showing in references

Tags: biblatex

this LaTeX code:

```
@ONLINE{Doe,
author = {Doe, Ringo},
title = {This is a test entry of type {@ONLINE}},
month = jun,
year = {2009},
url = {http://www.test.org/doe/}
}
```

generates this output (reference 3):

[image]

How can I fix the code to show the URL?

Comment: Would you mind sharing a complete - but of course minimal - [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/) with us? We would certainly need to know what packages you use to create the bibliography (`natbib`, `biblatex`, `cite`) and what style you use.

Comment: Try `url = "http://www.test.org/doe/"`

Comment: url = "http://www.test.org/doe/" still not shows the URL

Comment: @moewe I am using bibtex

Comment: I'm afraid that piece of information is not sufficient to help you. Please provide a proper [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As others have written, it is not clear how you are using this. Suppose for example you have that bib entry in a file `url.bib` and then just

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{url}
\end{document}
```

That will give a result similar to the one you got. Maybe this is how you have done it. In that case you should have noticed that there was a warning when you ran Bibtex:

```
Warning--entry type for "Doe" isn't style-file defined
```

That is, this default style doesn't know about the `@online` entry type. (So it shows the normal fields in some normal way, but really doesn't know about that `url` field.)

The traditional way of entering entries like this in Bibtex is like

```
@Misc{doemisc,
  author =   {Doe, Ringo},
  title =    {This is a test entry of type {@ONLINE}},
  howpublished = {\url{http://www.test.org/doe/}},
  month =    jun,
  year =     2009}
```

Use `\usepackage{url}` in your document to get the `\url` command.

There may be other Bibtex styles that define an entry type `@online` but chances are you've seen this because Biblatex has such an entry field. So this LaTeX file using Biblatex can use a bib file with the entry you cited.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{url.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: using 
@Misc{doemisc,
  author =   {Doe, Ringo},
  title =    {This is a test entry of type {@ONLINE}},
  howpublished = {\url{http://www.test.org/doe/}},
  month =    jun,
  year =     2009} works for me thank you!

Answer (score 18):

This easy way worked for me:

Use `\bibliographystyle{plainurl}` instead of just "`plain`". This solved everything for me. Enter that command after `\bibliography{...}`.

Remember to put `\usepackage{url}`.

Comment: best simplest answer, thx !

Comment: The only answer working for me!

Comment: This idea worked for `abbrvurl` as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the `\bibliographystyle{plain}`, then use the below format in your `.bib` file:

```
@inproceedings{vqa-url,
    note = {\url{https://visualqa.org}},
}
```

and then, to cite the URL in the LaTeX document, simply do:

```
\cite{vqa-url}
```

which will then give the plain URL as the result in your **references** section:

```
https://visualqa.org
```

and a corresponding number in the actual text section.

Note: Also, there is **no** need to use `\usepackage{url}` in the header section. But, if you want the URL in the references section to be clickable then you MUST use `\usepackage{hyperref}` in the header section of your LaTeX document.

Comment: This is already covered in pst's answer above. Besides, there's J R's suggestion to use `plainurl`, which is possibly better.

Comment: I tried pst's answer but that doesn't work. In addition, I added some more info about how to make the URL clickable

Comment: Short answer made for a better read for me. Upvoted